# Border of elements not displaying correctly

Tags: angular, primeng

Why isn't the border of the drop-down displaying correctly?
It seems like other components overlap but I don't know how to fix it.

```html
<div class="ui-g">
  <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-6 ui-fluid">
    <label for="">Inicio Traslado:</label>  
    <p-dropdown [options]="" [autoWidth]="false"></p-dropdown>
     
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-6 ui-fluid ">
     
    <div class="ui-g ">
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12">
        <label for="">Fin Traslado:</label>
        <p-dropdown [options]="" [autoWidth]="false"></p-dropdown>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ">
        <label for="">Fecha autorización:</label>
        <p-dropdown [options]="" [autoWidth]="false"></p-dropdown>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just style it with CSS like you would anything else. Use the console inspector to determine the CSS path.

You will need to use [ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) if you are going to use CSS.

Alternatively, you can pass in styles to primeng components.

This latter approach is preferred since ng-deep is deprecated but still works for now.

Or your 3rd choice, just use the global stylesheet.

Finally, make sure you have chosen the correct version of bootstrap - primeng supports 3 and 4 but you must choose one or the other.

component.css should look like:

```
::ng-deep .your-class {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have been trying ur first 2 answers, because there is a lots of css and i think could be something i am missing, for ur third, am not using bootstrap just primeng or i miss something, i dont understand ? thanks for ur reply

Comment: forget bootstrap, it seems it only applies to certain primeng themes - focus on using ng-deep or the global stylesheet - also use CSS !important if you need to - have added an ng-deep example to my answer